# What is wrong with this QUERY, why it is giving me following error?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

I'm learning swing in java. I've make a jtable that is populated by database's values (sql table --> user(id, name, age)). I want to make jtable that is if i change values from jtable is should also update database on click on button. but where i query is executed an error occurs. I want to know what is issue with this query ???

QUERY:

```
String sql = "UPDATE \'alarm bell marshal\' SET mr = \'" + mrs.get(row) +
                "\' , shop = \'" +shops.get(row)+ "\' where id = \'" + ids.get(row) + "\'";
```

ERROR:

> SEVERE: null
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''alarm bell marshal' SET mr = '0' , shop = '0' where id = '1'' at line 1

Comment: AFAIU there is no (Java) reason to escape single quotes. Is it necessary for SQL syntax?

Comment: better use prepare statement for this scenario

Comment: please read about SQL Injection vulnerabilities and use use prepared statement.

Comment: Bobby tables loves this. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Since this is MariaDB, I suppose it has the same syntax as MySQL, which allows using **backticks** around identifiers such as table names and columns. Note the difference between single quotes ' and backticks `.

Comment: Please don't use space in the names `'alarm bell marshal`, if so, use RealSkeptic comment

Comment: @RealSkeptic when i use this query it works,

 String sql = "UPDATE admins SET name =\'" + names.get(row) + "\' , password = \'" + passwords.get(row)+ "\' where id =\'" +ids.get(row)+ "\'";

Comment: Right, because `admins` doesn't have quotes around it like `'alarm bell marshal'`. @AxelH is right in that you shouldn't have table names that include spaces, but if you insist on having those, you need to use backticks, not single quotes, which in SQL denote literal strings, not identifiers.

Comment: thanks to all It works :)

Answer (score 0):

try use something how that:

```
String sql = 'UPDATE `alarm bell marshal` SET `mr` = "' + mrs.get(row) + '" , `shop` = "' + shops.get(row) + '" WHERE `id` = "' + ids.get(row) + '"';
```